# gwt-spring-hibernate application doesn't work after few minutes

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, gwt

as I said in my Title I have my app which works perfectly in dev mode. But after deployment in tomcat server it works only for few minutes and stop working. The complete stack trace is below:

```
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.util.List ci.apmt.itruck.client.daoservice.BillOfLadingService.findAllEtat(ci.apmt.itruck.shared.dto.EtatDossierDTO)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:415)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:571)
at org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.processCall(SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.java:37)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:831)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at ci.apmt.itruck.server.dao.BillOfLadingDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ac5b7bcb.findEtat(<generated>)
at ci.apmt.itruck.server.dao.serviceimpl.BillOfLadingServiceImpl.findAllEtat(BillOfLadingServiceImpl.java:138)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:58)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy794.findAllEtat(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
... 27 more
Caused by: ci.apmt.itruck.client.util.MesExceptions
at ci.apmt.itruck.server.AfterThrowingIntercept.errorInterceptor(AfterThrowingIntercept.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:603)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
... 47 more
```

below my applicationcontext.xml file:

```
<tx:annotation-driven order="200"/>

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="ci.apmt.itruck" />
 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

and my persistence.xml:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.storeManagerType" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer"
            value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apmt" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />

        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />
    </properties>
```

Comment: Your code is throwing the ci.apmt.itruck.client.util.MesExceptions. Without knowing why that is being thrown it will be difficult to resolve.

Comment: okok I use AOP to catch all the exception due to Hibernate so the  DataAccessException  are converted in Mesexceptions.